# Simple deform modifier maintaining perfect circles?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I have here a set of faces that are being arrayed, then being deformed with the simply deform modifier to form a circle, the trouble is on the faces I need perfect circles. Is it possible to maintain perfect circles throughout the simple deform operation? I tried using the vertex groups but that doesn't seem to work. [image]

Comment: hello, what do you mean exactly? Simple Deform gives you a perfect circle, and this is what it seems to be on your screenshot. Maybe give additional details?

Comment: You want the little insets to remain circular?

Comment: Robin Betts is correct I want the insets to remain circular.